# Combining C# String.Format format options

Tags: c#, string, formatting, format, string-formatting

I'd like to format my number as a percent value with an always visible sign.

To format it as a percent value I can do:

```
string.Format("{0:P2}", 1.45);
```

For visible signs I'll do:

```
string.Format("{0:+#.##;-#.##;0}", 1.45);
```

Any way to combine the two?

Comment: Please prefer string interpolation over `string.Format`. The readability improvements are dramatic.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I would if I was working in a newer .NET.

Comment: Well, upgrade! You can downlevel many language features to older runtimes besides. Here is a helpful reference on format specifiers: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx P.S: Google is my friend and yours too :)

Comment: I would argue the easiest option is something like this `(1.45 < 0 ? "-" : "+") + String.Format("{0:P2}", 1.45);`, provided your .NET version predicament

Comment: I would upgrade if i could :))) Can you refrain from posting if you're not helping with the original question?

Comment: Hmm.. is adding `%` symbol to custom format is so unobvious?

Comment: Fine, I will leave you alone, even though the link I posted applies to all string format operations, interpolated or otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably just want to add `%` to [custom format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string.Format("{0:+#.##%;-#.##%;0}", 1.45); // output +145%
```

Comment: No need to repeat the # twice after the `.` . Why you don't just use it like this `string.Format("{0:+#.#%;-#.#%;0}", 1.45);`

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad, tbh I was simply copy-pasting OP input. But what you suggest is not the same `#.#` and `#.##` results are different, try yourself with `1.45678`.